# how to install mysql server on CentOS

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, centos

I am new to linux platform.
can anybody help me in installation of mysql on CentOs.
I have downloaded mysql from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads), now i want to install it on CentOS, but not getting how to do that. after installation of mysql, how can i use JDBC in CentOs.
i hv installed jdk1.6.

Thanx in advance

Khushi

Answer (score 4):

```
yum -y install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

After this, execute the command `mysql_secure_installation`.

This will help you to secure your MySQL installation, including `mysql` root password.

Answer (score 3):

CentOS use yum:

search package:`yum search package-name`

install package:`yum install package-name`

For your case, you already downloaded the package manually, you can use: `rpm -i package-name`

Comment: and mysql server package name is mysql-server. So you need to `yum install mysql-server` and `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` to start it.

Comment: rvs: thanx for your reply. now can you tell me what settings i have to do for JDBC with mysql.

Comment: no additional setting is needed for you to use jdbc -- that's all java related, search ‘java mysql' on google will give you a lot link.